# Wordpress image slider overlay issues

Tags: css, wordpress

I've build a WordPress website which runs the TouchFolio theme. This theme uses a plugin called Royal Slider to create the sliding image gallery featured on the main page.

http://www.suellewelyn.com.au/

https://dimsemenov.com/themes/touchfolio/

https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/

I've ran into an issue where the description overlay on the RoyalSlider plugin is staying active across different projects, which results in them becoming mislabelled.

To recreate the issue, if you load the page at http://www.suellewelyn.com.au/ the first work titled "Primal Intent" comes up. If you then use the left hand menu to jump directly to a project lower down the list ("Celebration" for example) the "Primal Intent" title and description stays active. I noticed that this is an issue with demo of the theme on the developer's website as well.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might be able to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Just Increase z-index of your pseudo element with tint.